# How much information can be sniffed at tor exit nodes

Tags: tor

When someone is sniffing data at a Tor exit node, how much information can be obtained? The IP can be revealed, but can they see everything you do?
Does it make a difference if it is encrypted using https, or if it is a hidden service link?

Comment: Your IP will not be revealed (unless there are some javascript attacks - when surfing via Tor, you should use the http://noscript.net/ plugin, or equivalent.)

Comment: Hey, I'm using tor on android(orweb browser using orbot plugin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every unencrypted thing that passes through that exit node can be seen, for as long as you use the node.  That means plain `http`, but it also means `POP3`, `SMTP`, and `IMAP` email, telnet sessions, etc.

Things that cannot be seen: your IP address, the contents of anything going over `https` or other encrypted protocols (but various side-channel attacks, such as monitoring packet sizes, are possible), or hidden service connections (those don't use an exit node).

Comment: @ Mark hey, so when you're using hidden services data can't be intercepted and decrypted by anyone? I mean even the guys like N.I.A?

Comment: Be wary as HTTPS can also be sniffed, depending on how you reach the HTTPS page.

Comment: @Alex...How are HTTPS sniffed? And what about .onion links

Comment: @RichmondWilliams, .onion links are encrypted end-to-end.  Barring a three-letter agency finding a vulnerability in the encryption, only you and the .onion server know what you're talking about.  On the other hand, the *fact* that you're talking isn't as secure: .onion servers are almost as vulnerable to confirmation attacks as the rest of TOR (it's a bit harder, since the first step requires *finding* the server).